# Partially evaluate an expression in R

Tags: r, expression, eval, evaluate, expr

Sorry.
I have an expression:
#x^p

I want to evaluate this for a given p.

```
p -> 0
# 1 

p -> 1
#x

p -> 2
#x^2

p -> 3
#x^3

p -> -1
#x^-1
```

If I type in:

```
p -> 1
eval(p)
#1
```

BUT

```
p -> 1
eval(x^p)
```

Gives the error:
#Error in eval(x^p) : object 'x' not found

I want it to give:
#x

For
p -> 2
, I want to get:
#x^2
For
p -> 0
, I want to get:
#1

Comment: What is the question? also, if p = 0, then you get 1.

Comment: When I use eval(), I want to give some numerical values like p, but I don't want to give a value for x, so that I get an expression in x.

Comment: can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: I have changed my post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the update to your post, I think you want something like this. Note, you will need to have the packages `Ryacas` and `gsubfn` installed.

```r
#function
sub_fun <- function(exp, def){
  Ryacas::yac_symbol(gsubfn::gsubfn(".", def, exp))
}

#examples
sub_fun(exp = "x^p", def = list("p" = 0))
#> y: 1

sub_fun(exp = "x^p", def = list("p" = 1))
#> y: x

sub_fun(exp = "x^p", def = list("p" = 2))
#> y: x^2

sub_fun(exp = "x^p", def = list("p" = 2, "x" = 3))
#> y: 9

sub_fun(exp = "p*x^p-(p^x-p)", def = list("p" = 2))
#> y: 2*x^2-(2^x-2)

sub_fun(exp = "p*x^p-(p^x-p)", def = list("p" = 2, "x" = 3))
#> y: 12
```